# how to crawl multiple URLs?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to enter multiple links and scrape their data but i don't know how to code..

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time
from nhl.items import NHLItem


class NHL_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='NHL'
    allowed_domains=["nhl.com"]
    start_urls=["https://www.nhl.com/scores/2019-02-17"]
    

    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.browser=webdriver.Chrome("/users/박정균/chromedriver")

    
    def parse(self,response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)   
       
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="2018020904"]').click()
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-wrap"]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div/section/div/ul/li[2]/section/ul/li[3]/a').click()
        
        
        source=self.browser.page_source
        html=self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*').get_attribute('outerHTML')
        selector=Selector(text=html)
        
        rows = selector.xpath('//*[@class="statistics__season-stats"]/table/tbody/tr')
        
        
        for row in rows:
            item=NHLItem()
            item["Team"]=row.xpath('.//*[@class="media-heading small"]/text()')[0].extract()
            item["Shots"]=row.xpath('./td[2]/text()')[0].extract()
            item["FO"]=row.xpath('./td[3]/text()')[0].extract()
            item["PP"]=row.xpath('./td[4]/text()')[0].extract()
            yield item
```

This is one match's data. I want to increase number `xpath('//*[@id="201802090{here}"]')` and `xpath('//*[@id="content-wrap"]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div/section/div/ul/li[{here}]/section/ul/li[3]/a')` (here spot) at the same time because of next match.
Simply, `2018020904,2018020905,2018020906` and `li[2],li[3],li[4]` in pairs.

Comment: " but i don't know how to code.." Well no time like the present to learn

Comment: I become army soon,, I'm korean hahaha..Before going, I want to crawl simply but i'm beginner of beginner.